# Convention to express sets in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I need to express a set with a letter and its members also with that letter.

Say I have my set `S` with members `S1, S2, ..., SN`. I have three ways in mind. Which one should be adopted in paper writing?

Set `S`: `$S$`  Members: `$S_1, S_2, ..., S_N$`

OR

Set `S`: `$\bm{S}$`  Members: `$S_1, S_2, ..., S_N$`

OR

Set `S`: `$\{S\}$`  Members: `$S_1, S_2, ..., S_N$`

Comment: This is off topic, because it's a question about mathematical notation. The third option is meaningless, because usually “{S}” denotes a set with just one element. The only TeXnichal remark is that `\dots` should be used and not three periods.